# C# signing a xml document with out using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, xml-signature

Is there a way to sign a Xml file with out using classes form System.Security.Cryptography.Xml ?

Can the SignedXml.ComputeSignature() functionality be realized with a "manual" implementation ? something on the lines of :

1. Create the necesary elements in the Signature
2. Calculate the digest values with SHA512.ComputeHash()
3. Compute the SignatureValue using RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData() with the SignedInfo as an input

Any resource on how / what SignedXml.ComputeSignature() is actually doing would also be welkomed.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the SignedXml.ComputeSignature() functionality be realized with a "manual" implementation ?

Sure, but if you want to make a compatible signature you'll have to do all the same work.  Luckily the source code is published: https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography.Xml/System/Security/Cryptography/Xml/SignedXml.cs,ec07e01153e4b893

> Any resource on how / what SignedXml.ComputeSignature() is actually doing would also be welcomed.

SignedXml is an implementation of xmldsig 1.1: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/

Comment: Wich .Net version is this? .Net Core 5.0 ?

Comment: @PerG source.dot.net shows .NET’s main branch, maybe a few days out of date. But since SignedXml has had no feature work done on it since 2015 or so, that code is timeless.